# How to create three evenly spaced buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I was just wondering how can I create three evenly spaced buttons at the bottom of the screen. I was also wondering what style I could use to make these buttons appear neat and tidy.

The code I have written so far.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Fragment1"
                android:id="@+id/worldTextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button1"
           />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Button2"

                 />

            <Button
             android:id="@+id/Button3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/Button3"
            />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_width="0dp"` and 
                `android:layout_weight="1"` and make the width of linear layout `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" // wrap_content to match_parent
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fragment1"
                android:id="@+id/worldTextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent" // wrap_content t0 match_parent
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"  // specify the layout weight
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button1"
           />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Button2"

                 />

            <Button
             android:id="@+id/Button3"
              android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/Button3"
            />
   </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

snap shot

[image]

Edit:

You can also use a relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Fragment1" />

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1"
               />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button2"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button2"

                     />

                <Button
                 android:id="@+id/Button3"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Button3"
                />
       </LinearLayout>


       </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your three button in a different layout(Linear layout with orientation horizontal) at the bottom and give weight to each button and layout_width as zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative Layout.. Too many Linear Layouts will cause over burden while rendering the xml layout file.

Answer (score 1):

To evenly space your buttons, you can set each buttons `android:layout_width` to 0 and its `android:layout_weight` to 1 to make the width of each button the same.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Button2" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your linear layout will also need a `layout_width` that is non-zero and does not depend on its children (eg `wrap_content`). I've used `fill_parent` in this example but you could also use `match_parent` or a hard coded value such as `55dp`.

[This tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) is a decent in-depth guide on using `android:layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `android:layout_weight` for all three buttons.

```
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/Button1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/Button1"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 />

            <Button
             android:id="@+id/Button3"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/Button3"
             android:layout_weight="1"
            />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give LinearLayout a **weightSum** attribute and its child assign **layout_weight** attribute like in below code.

Then give **height and width of parent and child match_parent** this will allow your layout to adjust there height and width according to screen resolution and parent layout height and width.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum = "3">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/Button1"
       />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/Button2"

             />

        <Button
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:id="@+id/Button3"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="@string/Button3"
        />
```

Comment: Set the height to `match_parent` as well? Why would you need three buttons covering the entire screen?